# Two threads trying to access same List :" System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to threading . I have a List and 2 threads T1 and T2.

```
private readonly List<item> myCompletedItems;
```

I have a method which sets the collection

```
public void ItemCreated(item theitem)
{
this.myCompletedItems.add(theitem);
}
```

I have another method which gets a field value of first item:

```
public int GetStartItemId()
{          
  return this.myCompletedItems[0].id;                
}
```

Thread 1 is adding items to "myCompletedItems".But even before an item is added to list, Thread 2 is trying to access the list and throwing "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range". How do i make Thread 2 wait until all the items are added to list by Thread 1?

Comment: You throw a ball to a friend and they try to throw that ball to another friend. If you don't synchronize what will happen? Someone gets a ball in the face... This is even worse than that, you have hardwired the fact that there is always a ball in someone's hand. Firstly you need to use a `lock` to synchronise the list access, secondly, you need to (at minimum) check if there is actually array element 0 (in the lock as well)

Comment: Might want to start with some reading about basic thread-safety issues and dealing with such - https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/07/09/thread-safety/ ; in this case a `lock` is sufficient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: You are trying to implement something called `producer/consumer problem`. It is not easy to get this right. I recommend you do a bit of reding on this. You might find this useful https://makolyte.com/event-driven-dotnet-concurrent-producer-consumer-using-blockingcollection/

Comment: Can i use Blocking Collection here ?

Comment: Sure you can, however, what are you actually trying to do, this will allow someone to better answer the question. That's to say, if you explain why you need this, what problem you are trying to solve, there maybe lots of suitable patterns and solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular lists are not thread safe, and just about anything can happen when trying to use it from multiple threads concurrently.

> How do i make Thread 2 wait until all the items are added to list by Thread 1?

Use a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) if you want to ensure two threads does not access the resource concurrently, or a [manualResetEvent/autoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=net-5.0) to block a thread until another thread does something.

Or more practically, use [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

However, multi threading is not a good place to mess around and try things randomly. This will very easily result in bugs that are very hard to reproduce. Multi threading is difficult even for experienced programmers, and you should have a fairly good knowledge of potential hazards like [deadlocks and race conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices) *before* trying to use multi threading. See also [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), these are in part done to avoid the need for manual synchronization between threads.